# how to create Navigationbar in android?

Tags: android, navigationbar

> How can we create Navigation bar in android can any one help me
>   regarding this?

Comment: increase your accpetance rate

Answer (score 1):

Try this For Bottom Navigation Bar:-------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/back_button" 
    android:text="Back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/home_button" 
    android:text="Home" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/next_button" 
    android:text="Next" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this help.